# configuring rails to send email via the microsoft live smtp server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, outlook

There is a lot of information in rails about setting up rails to [work with gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026098/sending-email-from-gmail-rails-3) and I have done this for a personal (e.g. myemail@gmail.com ) website.
Now unfortunately google apps for businesses no longer offers free mail hosting but as it says [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-setup-a-professional-branded-email-address-with-outlook-com/) apparently outlook do.
so I followed the instructions, changed my DNS MX records and everything and set up smtp (similar to the google version like [so](http://email.about.com/od/Outlook.com/f/What-Are-The-Outlook-com-Smtp-Server-Settings.htm) )
this gives me (eg from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810580/rails-3-smtp-settings-for-hotmail-live-hosted-email)):

```
config.action_mailer.deconfig.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.live.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'mydomain.com'
  :user_name            => 'username',
  :password             => 'mypass',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

ahh. I have finally solved this, I figure I'll post it to save somebody else the hassle. I had massive headaches trying to get this microsoft server to send from any address, my solution is now to use [mandrill](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks) it's easy to configure and free for less than 12k emails per month.
(DISCLAIMER: I have no connection to Mandrill, please let me know any tips to allow the microsoft server to work, I couldn't and half a day was enough for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have basically identical settings as you but mine is working. I'm guessing your user_name is wrong, it should be

```
:user_name => "username@mydomain.com"
```

and also make sure you've at least logged in once to your newly created account to activate it

Comment: ah, thanks, I can't remember whether I tried that (that could have been the problem). Cheers for the help.